# Update HighCharts every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am using this code to render a HighChart:

```
  <script>
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container1',
           title: '',
           type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["<?php echo  join($data0, '","') ?>"],
            title: {
                text: 'Month'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Orders'
            }
        },
        series: [{
           name: '<?php echo  date("Y",strtotime("-1 year")); ?>',
           color: '#666666',
           data: [<?php echo  join($data1, ',') ?>]
        }, {
           name: '<?php echo  date("Y"); ?>',
           color: '#2196F3',
           data: [<?php echo  join($data2, ',') ?>]
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
  });
  </script>
```

How can get this to update every 5 seconds and show some indication on the chart if something changes?

Comment: Have you seen http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how to use that but with real data like I am using? That example just seems to randomly increase values to give an example.

Comment: if you have an url that returns the chartoptions you can simply poll with ajax and reinitiate the graph, what problem you have ?

Comment: Just read our [tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-live-data) for getting live data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setInterval(function(){
    chart.series[0].update({
        data: [<?php echo  join($data1, ',') ?>]
    }, true);

    chart.series[1].update({
        data: [<?php echo  join($data2, ',') ?>]
    }, true);
}, 5000);
```